# Can't open databse requested by login, login failed, login failed for user

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2012, mdf

I have developed c# WPF application, I am using MDF file for database,
   my connection string looks like :

> Data
>      Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\appDataBase.mdf;Integrated
>      Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

here I am replacing **|DataDirectory|** with **user's appdata folder**.

the database file is in **user's appdata folder**, I created a setup which
   copies `.mdf` file to _users appdata folder when I install it in
   client's computer, it works perfectly
but when I uninstalls and
   reinstall it, I am not able to connect that file, getting the error:

> Can't open  database
>      "C:/users/myusername/appdata/roaming/myapplication/database/appDataBase.mdf"
>      requested by login, login failed, login failed for user..

File is there, but somehow it is used by SQL server and can't
   open it. also while starting application every time I am creating
   backup of that file, that one also failing with error

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>      'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\myapplication\Database\appDataBase.mdf'
>      because it is being used by another process.

Can anybody give me exact solution, because i have to use localdb only on my client computer , i don't want them let to do any extra configuration for installation of my app, i.am still facing iasue after i changed my code to close db connection on main window closing event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of things happens because one of your object which is using that database is still running in the background so please dispose all the database related instance also dispose and close all the database related object in catch().

Try catch will help you to detect exact line number where you are getting error and also show due to which object you are getting error.

If you want to check why this is happening then open task manager and look out for services there you definitely find service which is holding object for database.

Comment: so, when application starts i have to check for any open connection to mdf file? and disconnect if it was open from last execution?

Comment: No just put your code in try catch and dispose and close all the object in try as well as in catch so it will never create the same problem. As looking for an instance and closing it is not a good practice. May be you have open a connection for database and the forget to make it close look for that.

Comment: I was researching and found that i shouldn't use (LocalDB)\v11.0, instead it should be .SQLEXPRESS , i am installing SQL express in clients computer by specifying in my application prerequisites , and it is working first time with (LocalDB)\v11.0,

Comment: Yes its better to use SQLEXPRESS but you are facing running instance issue and reason behind it was instance cannot be released while your application has not been in running condition. Same problem will arise in near future if some error will appear in SQL transaction operation.

Comment: Can anybody give me exact solution, because i have to use localdb only on my client computer , i don't want them let to do any extra configuration for installation of my app.

Comment: @JoanaBrandão, Have you checked for processes in Task Manager which is holding instance. Just have to stop them.